# C program printing twice

Tags: c

So I have a program I am working on checking if the year is a leap year, and then depending if it is a leap or not i will give the day number of the year from (1-366).. I got this code below i have worked on so far, when i type in a non leap year i get a normal answer, but when i type in a leap year i get the displayDate(day) run twice and prints two times, copy paste my code and try it for yourself, tell me what is wrong with it please.. also i am new to C so take it easy if it is something very simple please

```
int main ()
{
  int day ,month , year, LeapOrNot, date ;

  printf("PLease enter a date in the following format Month/day/year:  ");
  scanf("%d/%d/%d" , &month , &day , &year );

  LeapOrNot = isLeap(year);
  switch (LeapOrNot)
  {
    case 1 :
        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                date = day;
                break;
            case 2:
                date = 31 + day;
                break;
            case 3 :
                date = 60 + day;
                break;
            case 4 :
                date = 91 + day;
                break;
            case 5 :
                date = 121 + day;
                break;
            case 6:
                date = 152 + day;
                break;
            case 7:
                date = 182 + day;
                break;
            case 8 :
                date = 213 + day;
                break;
            case 9 :
                date = 244 + day;
                break;
            case 10:
                date = 274 + day;
                break;
            case 11 :
                date = 305 + day;
                break;
            case 12 :
                date = 335 + day;
                break;
        }
        displayDate(date);
    case 0 :
        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                date = day;
                break;
            case 2:
                date = 31 + day;
                break;
            case 3 :
                date = 59 + day;
                break;
            case 4 :
                date = 90 + day;
                break;
            case 5 :
                date = 120 + day;
                break;
            case 6:
                date = 151 + day;
                break;
            case 7:
                date = 181 + day;
                break;
            case 8 :
                date = 212 + day;
                break;
            case 9 :
                date = 243 + day;
                break;
            case 10:
                date = 273 + day;
                break;
            case 11 :
                date = 304 + day;
                break;
            case 12 :
                date = 334 + day;
                break;
        }
        displayDate(date);
  }     
}

int isLeap(int year)
{
  int LeapOrNot;
  if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 ==0)
    LeapOrNot = 1 ;
  else 
    LeapOrNot = 0 ;
  return LeapOrNot;
}

int displayDate(int date )
{
  printf("the day for that year is %d", date);  
}
```

Comment: Try stepping through the code in a debugger line by line. The program is small enough that this is feasible. Once you do, you'll discover where the problem is.

Comment: A good practice (since you are a beginner) would be to add a `default` statement too.

Comment: It is OK, to implement `isLeap()` and `displayDate()` after `main()`. For better code, you should insert prototypes for the former two before `main()`. (Prototypes are "function declarations" i.e. the head of the function with a `;` instead of the body.) I'm also missing a `#include <stdio.h>` at the very beginning.

Comment: @SreetamDas I would even suggest a `default: assert(0);` to detect unexpected values in `LeapOrNot`.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the outer `switch (LeapOrNot)` if you add `LeapOrNot` to `date` if `month >= 3`. This could be done in every branch of `switch (month)` with `case` >= 3 or you insert a line before the call of `displayDate(date);`: `if (month >= 3) date += LeapOrNot;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have break statement for

```
switch (LeapOrNot)
{
    case 1 :
```

So it will go on executing case 0: code as well and call displayDate twice

Comment: Wow.. incredible.. Been trying to find what the hell is wrong with it and you just found it like that, thanks a lot man appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impress your teacher you could present him this slightly shorter variant as alternative (`leapOrNot.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isLeap(int year);

void displayDate(int date);

int main()
{
  int day, month, year, leapOrNot, date;
  int dates[] = { 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334 };

  printf("PLease enter a date in the following format Month/day/year: ");
  scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

  date = dates[month - 1] + day + (month >= 3) * isLeap(year);
  displayDate(date);

  return 0;
}

int isLeap(int year)
{
  return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0;
}

void displayDate(int date)
{
  printf("The day for that year is %d.\n", date);
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o leapOrNot leapOrNot.c 

$ ./leapOrNot
PLease enter a date in the following format Month/day/year: 3/1/2016
The day for that year is 61.

$ ./leapOrNot
PLease enter a date in the following format Month/day/year: 3/1/2017
The day for that year is 60.

$ ./leapOrNot
PLease enter a date in the following format Month/day/year: 12/31/2016
The day for that year is 366.

$ ./leapOrNot
PLease enter a date in the following format Month/day/year: 12/31/2017
The day for that year is 365.

$
```

Though, the use of `switch` might have been an assignment and this implementation comes without any...

Notes:

1. Instead of using a `switch` statement the offsets (depending on `month`) are stored in an array.
2. `(month >= 3) * isLeap(year)` is typical C programming.
   `(month >= 3)` yields 1 if true and 0 otherwise.
   `isLeap()` yields 1 or 0, also.
   Multiplying both values yields again 1 or 0.
   Thus, the result may be simply added.
   C programmers are very sensitive for effeciency. Thus, the multiply is considered as faster alternative for an `if`.
3. I changed the return type of `displayDate()` from `int` to `void` because the function does not return any value. I'm a little bit surprised that the C compiler didn't warn about this before I did. (May be, I had to have raised the compilers warning level to get one.)
4. In the `main()` function, the `return 0;` may be left out. (This is one of the strange exceptions in the C standard.) However, it is usually considered as "better style" to denote it explicitly.

Comment: @AliSoujod I added some notes to explain in more detail what I did and why.